# Github responds with "Repository cant be finished"

Tags: github

I am trying to transfer ownership of a repo that I started to another github account.  I get the notice in my gaining account that asks for permission of transfer.  I click on the link in the email.  Github responds with "Sorry, this repository transfer can’t be finished."  Is there a source to figure out why?

I just successfully transfered my first repo just before trying this repo and everything went good.  successful transfer.  Just having problems with this second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly solved this by clearing browser cache in IE.  Too simple.

Answer (score 19):

Seems like for me, the problem was that I needed to log into the receiving account before accepting from the email.